# Best way to find the class of an class attribute

Tags: ruby, json, object

I am hitting rock after rock with Ruby, but I keep fighting.
Today I have the problem of indentifying an attribute.

I am working on serializing objects to JSON, and my objects look something like this, where in the attributes Items is an object with objects of type Item inside, and address is an object.

```
    module OrderSet
  class OrderObject

    attr_accessor :items, :url, :email, :address, :id

    def initialize args = nil
      if args != nil
        args.each do |k, v|
          instance_variable_set("@#{k}", v) unless v.nil?
        end
      end
    end

    def to_json
      hash = {}
      self.instance_variables.each do |var|
        # [1..-1] is to get rid of the leading @ from instance variables. This is so the API knows the variables.
        hash[var[1..-1]] = self.instance_variable_get var
      end
      hash.to_json
    end
  end
end
```

If I serialize this, it ends up with a JSON like this (sorry for the mess, but it will not format as it is not a valid JSON...:

```
"{"address":"{\"name\":\"Ruby\",\"line1\":\"StoneStreet\",\"city\":\"Gemstones\",\"country\":\"The WOrld\",\"postCode\":\"4004VC\"}","items":"[\"{\\\"productId\\\":\\\"canvas_a60x60\\\",\\\"files\\\":\\\"{\\\\\\\"content\\\\\\\":\\\\\\\"http://i.imgur.com/uHZfjIU.jpg\\\\\\\"}\\\",\\\"quantity\\\":10,\\\"pageCount\\\":1,\\\"metaData\\\":\\\"test\\\"}\"]","email":"test@test.test"}"
```

How it needs to look:
`"{"address":"{"name":"Ruby",
"line1":"StoneStreet",
"city":"Gemstones",
"country":"The WOrld",
"postCode":"4004VC"
}","items":"["{

"productId":"canvas_a60x60",
"files":"{"content":"http://i.imgur.com/uHZfjIU.jpg"
}","quantity":10,
"pageCount":1,
"metaData":"test"
}"]",
"email":"test@test.test"
}"`

Now each class does have its own to_json method, and it needs to be invoked and put in the hash of the origional to_json method. I have come up with a few solutions:

1. Do a `object.is_a?(ClassName)`
2. Check the module (i've got 4 modules, containing around 20 classes in total, so the first one is way longer than the second one)
3. to make one base object, extend all other objects to that one, check if it is a child of the base object and invoke to_json accordingly (putting the to_json in the parrent)
4. Maybe a static method, but I don't know if it will work as it calls `instance_variables`

[edit]
woops, forgot to ask the question, is there a better way than one of the above, and if not, wich of the above is the best?

Comment: What's the connection between checking the class of these items and JSON serialisation?

Comment: @FrederickCheung That the classes that are in the attributes (with their own attributes) do not get serialized properly. If you look at the provided JSON you see a boat load of backslashes, they only occur on objects that are my own, and added to the attributes. But that is not what I need.

I will make the given JSON valid, and provide that as how it needs to look. Then you will be able to see.

Comment: Your output looks as though you've called to_json on a hash where the values were already strings generated by calling to_json. Perhaps the implementation of to_json on the child classes is faulty.

Comment: @FrederickCheung So you say if I say orderObject.to_json it invokes the to_json on the attribute classes? If so, how would that work? I am getting more and more confused by the minute. But I keep fighting to understand it, I keep running tests to figure this out.

Comment: that's not what I was saying. The to_json method on Hash will call to_json on all the values, so their implementations matter.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a lot of meta programming, as a simple test, try and write what you're expecting is actually happening under all that:

```
def to_json
  hash = {}
  hash["address"] = @address
  hash.to_json
end
```

From there, try and figure out where your bug is.

Edit:

For example:

```
class Address
  def to_json(options={})
    {"name" => "foo"}.to_json
  end
end

order_set = OrderSet::OrderObject.new({"address" => Address.new })
order_set.to_json
```

Is this what you're after?

```
module JSONable
  def to_json(options={})
    hash = {}
    self.instance_variables.each do |var|
      hash[var[1..-1]] = self.instance_variable_get var
    end
    hash.to_json
  end
end


class Address
  include JSONable
  # Rest of code
end
```

Comment: I have tried looking for classes and methods. As long as I do not have a nested object, everything goes as planned. But when the object comes to play... it does not work...

Comment: Ahh I see, I tested it. The Address object does need a to_json method when you call to_json on the hash.Fredrick Cheung is correct, it's probably a bug in the Address class to_json method. Also JSON.parse is a good way to test.

Comment: It is the exact same to_json method, that's why my question also includes to make it maybe like a bit more DRY, to make one main class and move the to_json to there so there is less of the same code everywhere.

Comment: Gotcha. I personally wouldn't DRY it up till I have 3 objects that you know will need the same behavior (whether you do it through modules or inheritance). Each object having their own implementation of to_json has it's advantages/disadvantages. It promotes duck types and that you trust your objects. It's up to you to hold off on DRYing it up for the sake of DRY.

Comment: `i've got 4 modules, containing around 20 classes in total` In my opening post, and they all use the same code, so that's why I want to DRY (pun intended)

Comment: I added an example how you could share the to_json code. This might not fix your bug, since I dont know what the Address class looks like.